# Does Twitter Bootstrap have any RTL or i18n support?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internationalization, right-to-left

I need to add right-to-left (RTL) support for my web site, already implemented with Twitter Bootstrap. As far as I can see, the distribution doesn't have any. Am I missing something? Are there any external library/framework/tools for that?

Comment: What do you mean by RTL support? And by i18n support? Is this about localizing the site (with alternate language versions)?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - By RTL I mean: Right To Left, which is a requirements for web sites in Arabic, Persian, Hebrew, etc. Document flows from right to left, menus are adjusted to the right, sub element are indented from right to left, etc.

Comment: Yes, but what specific support do you need? You can simply use `<body dir=rtl>`, whether you are using Twitter Bootstrap or not.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - there is more into it than just `dir=rtl`. Basically, everywhere when there is 'left' in the CSS (for example: float: left, margin-left: 10px), there should be 'right', and vice versa. There are few more subtle changes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[answering my own question]

**Lack** of RTL support in bootstrap is well known, discussed and documented issue. Apparently, there are discussions all over the web, specifically - in the GitHub project.

In GitHub, issue [#6409](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6409) is the most recent discussion, with the very promising [comment](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6409#issuecomment-11725361) from @mdo that this will come in 3.0.

In the mean time, there are several things one can do. By far, the easiest approach would be to use the RTL Bootstrap from Hamed Ramezanian. Hamed manually changed the source file (mostly, the *.less files), and built a comparable framework for Right to Left. He even converted the documentation, and created a Persian web site: http://rbootstrap.ir/ (I speak Hebrew, so the site isn't very useful for me). As of April 2013 the project is very well maintained, with the most recent Bootstrap drop (v2.3.1) converted.

Comment: Does it help in any way in creating a site that serves both LTR and RTL, or does it mean RTL users should get served with this variant rather than the original bootstrap?

Comment: As of today there is no BiDi (bi-directional) bootstrap solution. The rbootstrap is sort of "mirror" of the ltr bootstrap. On my own web site, I serve either bootstrap and rbootstrap, depends on the language of the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the rtl version of bootstrap from this site
http://rbootstrap.ir/
(for download click => http://rbootstrap.ir/assets/bootstrap.zip )